# Is it possible to write the images in android asset folder at run time

Tags: android, android-layout

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            //  "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            Log.d("Gallery displaying....!",""+intent);

            final File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Safe");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----


            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

      }
});`
```

I select image from gallery and save to sdcard but i need to save the images asset folder at run time please help any one......

Comment: It's not possible to save in _asset_ folder at runtime, only on sdcard. The _asset_ or _res_ folders cannot be modified after you compile the application, for apk.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to modify the assets folder at runtime. But you might want to store the data into the internal private storage. This storage can only be accessed by your application. Instructions can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).